# Weird float to integer conversion issue in python

Tags: python, numbers, rounding, number-formatting, calculation

For a calculation in program that I wrote that involves finite algebraic fields, I needed to check whether `(2**58-1)/61` was an integer. However python seems to indicates that it is, while it is [not](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%282%5E58-1%29%2F61).

For example -

```
>>> (2**58-1)/61
4725088133634619.0
```

Even when using `numpy` functions this issue appears -

```
>>> np.divide(np.float64(2**58)-1,np.float64(61))
4725088133634619.0
```

This happens although python does calculate `2**58` correctly (I assume this issue is general, but I encountered it using these numbers).

Answer (score 3):

If you use normal `/` division, your result is a float, with the associated limited precision. The result gets rounded, and in your case, it gets rounded to 4725088133634619.0 - but that doesn't prove that it is an integer.

If you want to check if the result of the division by 61 is an integer, test if the remainder of the division by 61 is 0, using the modulo operator:

```
>>> (2**58-1) % 61
45
```

As you can see, it isn't.

Comment: Thank you! But howcome when using `np.float64` the number is still rounded?

Comment: @proton: This number is exactly the right size for float precision to go down to the ones digit. The `.0` is superfluous and is there only to show that it's type is `float`.

Answer (score 1):

As for float limited precision mentioned by @Thierry Lathuille, Python's `float` uses `64` bits and is double-precision that provides `53` bits for mantissa (the same is true for `np.float64`). That means that not all numbers `> 2**53` are representable using the `float`, we have a loss of precision. For example, `2**53` == `2**53 + 1` is true in double precision. More detailed here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

[Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 0):

Correct answers have already been given. I am just adding another approach (which is not much different from what has already been said).

What you may want to do, due to inherent limitations of representation errors, is use divmod( ) for python and numpy.divmod( ) for numpy. That way you can check the quotient and the remainder.

```py
print(divmod((2**58-1),61))
```

Gives quotient and remainder as

```py
(4725088133634618, 45)
```

In numpy you may want to use similar, divmod, function but the numbers should be np.int type and not np.float type (due to representation errors mentioned above).

```py
np.divmod(np.int64(2**58)-1,np.int8(61))
```

The above gives quotient and remainder as.

```py
(4725088133634618, 45)
```